# $_GET method sporadically not passing any data.

Tags: php, mysql, get

so I have been building a small website with a content management system I have built using PHP and mysql. What I am trying to achieve is the user needs to be able to edit and delete the announcement posts they make, so I have been using $_GET to get the ID of the post that is to be edited/ deleted and chucked into a form which holds the code to do that.

Now, this is the code I have been using

```
if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    header('Location: announcement-edit.php?AnnouncementID='.$_GET['AnnouncementID']);  
}
```

The form later down the page to execute this is as follows

```
<form action="announcements.php" method="get">

<input type="hidden" name="AnnouncementID" value="<?php echo $row['AnnouncementID'];?>" />
    <input name="edit" value="Modify" type="submit">
    <input name="delete" value="Delete" type="submit" >
    </form>
```

This is where it confuses me, this code worked absolutely perfectly then all of a sudden last week it stopped, 2 days ago it started working again and now broken again. When the button is clicked the URL returns as;

url/folder/announcements.php?AnnouncementID=7&edit=Modify

When its supposed to return;

url/folder/announcement-edit.php?AnnouncementID=7

If i manually type the above in the url bar it works absolutely fine and I can update the rows in the DB.

Im totally stumped as to why it is so temperamental, Have I missed something out? am I trying to do this an out dated way?

Its not like I have just followed a random person on youtube how to do this I was actually shown this way at university (only last academic year) and we was told it was "good practice". Seems very weird it works perfectly one minute then refuses to work the next.

Any thoughts or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use form. You can do it simply using url and use  tag
Try to pass your parametr via get parametr like this:

```
<a href="announcements.php?AnnouncementID=<?php echo $row['AnnouncementID'];?>&edit=1">Edit</a>
<a href="announcements.php?AnnouncementID=<?php echo $row['AnnouncementID'];?>&delete=1">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I should have really thought of that when i said i could type the URL manually and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have two <kbd>submit</kbd> buttons in your form, which leads to triggering the submit event only once, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. So, when the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button is pressed, your `GET` parameters will have only `delete` entry and not the `edit` entry.

One way of tackling this is, give the same name to both and give a different value, as already there is a different value.

```
<form action="announcements.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="AnnouncementID" value="<?php echo $row['AnnouncementID'];?>" />
    <input name="action" value="Modify" type="submit" />
    <input name="action" value="Delete" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but i also have
    if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    header('Location: announcement-delete.php?AnnouncementID='.$_GET['AnnouncementID']);  
}

I didnt want to put both in because I wanted to keep it as clear as possible if I remove the delete button completely I still have the same problem.